# Calling javascript in csharp class

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a class. There is only deleteRecord function

```
protected virtual void DeleteRecord
{
    if(..)
    {}
    else(..)
    {
         Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Are you sure?')</script>", true);
    }
}
```

I want to show javascript message. But I think I made a mistake.
How can I do it?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? Have you debugged with your browser to see the resulting output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've added `true` to the last parameter on `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` which is `addScriptTags`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx

Therefore you have essentially added `<script>` within a `<script>`

Try this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert", "alert('Are you sure?')", true);
```

Also ensure the `key` parameter is unique to the page. If you already have a `StartupScript` with the key of "Alert" then this can also stop it from calling the JavaScript code.

Comment: You could also mention that this makes no sense at all. The user wants to delete a record, so he clicks on a delete-button, a postback happens, the server sends a javascript to the client with an `alert('Are you sure?')`. He clicks ok or cancel but nothing will happen in either way.

Comment: Very true @TimSchmelter. To be honest I skipped that only because the code example provided isn't very clear on the implementation. If this server-side approach is essential then @StackOver consider using a `return confirm('are you sure');` to only postback when the dialog is confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

I created this static class that I can call from any web page: (I use AJAX Toolkit for script manager, but you can use the default one in ASP.NET as well)

```
public static class ClientJS {
    public static void send(string js) {
        Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
        ToolkitScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "setTimeout(function(){" + js + "},1);", true);
    }
}
```

Use it like so:

```
ClientJS.send("alert('Are you sure?');");
```